# How to get the full content of string variable's value in debug mode in VSCode, when building Flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Ever since I've been working with flutter & vscode, I've had this nagging issue. But I haven't found a solution online yet.
When I put a breakpoint on a variable, and want to see its content, VSCode always displays only part of the content, and appends it with "..." Even when I go to the watch window and right click the "copyvalue" option, I get the truncated string instead of the full string. As seen below:
[image]

Please, does anybody know how to get the full value for this ?

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for this issue is to log the full details of the variable using the log() function. This way, you can view the complete content of the variable in the console output.

You can call this log() function whenever you want to inspect the content of a variable during debugging. It will print out the complete details in the console.

Additionally, if you're dealing with JSON responses and want to beautify them for better readability, you can use the getPrettyJSONString function provided below:

```
import 'dart:convert';

String getPrettyJSONString(jsonObject){
   var encoder = JsonEncoder.withIndent("     ");
   return encoder.convert(jsonObject);
}
```

You can pass your JSON object to this function, and it will return a formatted string with an indentation of four spaces for each level.

Comment: Thanks, I already do that. I need a real way to resolve this.